# Why is a generic argument that "extends" something not allowed in derived function, but generic return type is?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to override a generic function in a subclass, as follows:

Superclass:

```
public abstract class Metric {

    public abstract <T extends Foo> T precompute(); // valid syntax
    public abstract <T extends Foo> void distance(T arg); // valid syntax
    public static class Foo {}

}
```

Subclass:

```
public class MetricDefault extends Metric {

    @Override
    public Bar precompute() { return new Bar(); } // Valid - return type extends Foo

    @Override
    public void distance(Bar arg) {} // Invalid ??? - argument type extends foo

    public static class Bar extends Metric.Foo {}

}
```

The generic function, when the generic type is the return value of the function, is valid Java code and builds successfully.

Changing only the placement of the generic type - making it the argument to the function, rather than the return type - and it becomes invalid Java code.

Why is the latter case invalid?  What can I do to implement this functionality?

Comment: There are great solutions below, but I would like to add that the problem with your OP is that you are **overloading** method `distance` by specifying a subtype of `Foo`.  NetBeans complains that `@Override` should not be there since `distance` is not overriding any method from the super class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract class Metric<T extends Foo> {

    public abstract  T precompute(); // valid syntax
    public abstract void distance(T arg); // valid syntax
    public class Foo {}

}
```

then if as I understood Bar extends Foo:

```
public class MetricDefault extends Metric<Bar> {

    @Override
    public Bar precompute() { return new Bar(); } 

    @Override
    public void distance(Bar arg){} 

    public class Bar extends Foo {}

}
```

Comment: That's it, great!  One small detail - the code in your answer should read `<T extends Metric.Foo>` and `Metric<MetricDefault.Bar>`.

Answer (score 4):

The method declaration

```
public abstract <T extends Foo> void distance(T arg);
```

means that the method takes an `T` argument, and the caller can decide which subtype of `Foo` to use as `T`.

The method declaration

```
public abstract <T extends Foo> T precompute();
```

means that the method returns some object of type `T`, and the caller can decide which subtype of `Foo` to use as `T`.

This last method can't really be implemented (apart from returning `null`), since your method does not really know what an object to produce here.

In your concrete class you try to override the methods - for my understanding you shouldn't be allowed for both of them, but maybe the compiler is a bit more relaxed than me.

I think what you really want is something like what *Overbose* posted.

Answer (score 2):

Because the signature of `distance(T)` in the superclass specifies that someone that has a reference to a `Metric` should be allowed to pass any type that extends `Foo` as an argument.

The first method works fine because anyone referring to `Metric` is already prepared to handle the return type of `Bar`, since the signature refers to a parent type of `Bar`.

Comment: I intend that the signature `distance(T)` in the superclass specifies that anyone with a reference to a `Metric` should, indeed, be able to pass any type that extends `Foo`.  I do not see why that is a problem here.  In my subclass the function is, in fact, defined to pass a type that extends `Foo`.  Perhaps you (or someone) could elaborate?

Comment: if you have a `class Bizbat extends Foo`, can I pass it to `MetricDefault.distance(Bar)`? the method implementation will undoubtedly cause a ClassCastException. "In my subclass the function is, in fact, defined to pass a type that extends Foo" - the problem is that your subclass attempts to redefine `distance()` to operate on only one specific type of `Foo`. The `Metric` contract states that any `Foo` can be passed to this method, not just one type. To restrict a the type parameters of a class, use 0verbose's method, where the type parameter is declared at the class-level.

Comment: Very good.  i.e., `Metric metric = new MetricDefault(); metric.distance(new BizBat());` should be expected to succeed, since the compiler does not know that `metric` is really a `MetricDefault` and hence will accept the argument type `BizBat` (basing its acceptance criteria on the definition in `class Metric`) - BUT of course `metric` really *is* a `MetricDefault`, so (if it compiled, which it does not) at _runtime_ there would be a ClassCastException.  On the other hand, it's not possible to write `BizBat bizbat = metric.precompute()` - so the compiler is happy to allow Bar as return type.

Comment: Actually the latter should compile, because the only type parameter passed is what the caller chooses to store the response in. As mentioned earlier, what I believe you want to do in this situation is what 0verbose mentioned - type parameters defined as a part of the class definition (i.e. `Metric<Bar>`, `Metric<BizBat>` etc.

Comment: I've used Overbose's solution and it makes sense.  For my comment, I elaborated on your explanation of why the original code failed.  I wrote the following dummy code: `Metric metric = new MetricDefault(); BizBat bizbat = metric.precompute();` and in fact the compiler gives the error: _incompatible types_; whereas replacing the second line with `Foo bizbat = metric.precompute();` compiles fine.  Therefore, it seems that for both `distance` and `precompute` there is the possibility of a compiler error - for the former, at the point of method declaration, and for the latter, at the point of use.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need to make `T` a parameter of the type, rather than of the methods.

The way you are attempting to do it, your new method does not override the abstract base method.  After type erasure is performed, it amounts to the following code:

```
public abstract class Metric {
    public abstract Foo precompute(); // valid syntax
    public abstract void distance(Foo arg); // valid syntax
    public class Foo {}
}

public class MetricDefault extends Metric {
    public Bar precompute() { return new Bar(); } // Valid - return type extends Foo
    public void distance(Bar arg) {} // Signature not compatible - does not override distance(Foo)
    public class Bar extends Foo {}
}
```

Comment: Very useful presentation of what erasure does here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Paŭlo Ebermann mentioned, the following overriding should not be legal

```
    <T extends Foo>
    T   precompute();

    Bar precompute()
```

Rules in JLSv3 #8.4.8.3 and #8.4.5 forbid this overriding. Javac should have reported error on it.

There are 2 possible explanations

1. the spec omitted an intuitive&obvious rule: the "is return-type-substitutable" relation should be transitive. `T->Foo->Bar`, `Bar` overriding `T` is legal.
2. javac is buggy. It somehow mistakes `Foo` as the return type of method#1 when validating the overriding.

The 1st explanation is quite implausible. If the (nastily defined) relation is transitive, it's too hard to check if it holds for 2 arbitrary types. So the 2nd explanation is probably truer.

Comment: I had just started to solidify my understanding that it *is* legal, since it builds without error.  However (as I describe in a comment to @matt b), the compiler *does* give an error when you attempt to *call* the function `precompute` with anything but an explicit `Foo` as the return type (a Bar fails).  Perhaps that explains why the above construction (appears to be) legal?